# creating input form with squares for each character in css

Tags: html, css

i need some help for my web programming assignment; i have to create a form input like shown below using ONLY html and css (so no js).

[image]

no, i'm not allowed to use an input field for each square

Comment: then what do you wanted to add as input editable div?

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you post the current code and mention exactly what works and what doesn't.

Comment: @Toby right now i haven't written any css code for it, since i initially tried to make an input for each square before reading i'm not allowed;

Comment: @Dipakchavda i'm allowed to use input, not just one input for each square; i'm not sure how to explain it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21131678/seperate-boxes-for-each-letter-in-an-input-field

Comment: @radunicolae The accepted answer has no JavaScript.

Comment: @Edward yes, i've replied before reading the whole thing (me stupid) then deleted said reply; thanks, that's just what i needed.

Comment: is this a homework or something ?? the same question asked 3 times now by different people

Comment: @TemaniAfif it was for me; I'd close this thread, since I've found the answer, but I don't know how.

Comment: well i replied to the same one here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476209/making-a-custom-input-text-type/49476415#49476415 ... you can either delete the question, accpet the answer below if it's the one you are looking for, or simply do nothing ;)

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use a repeating background image, either a vertical line or in the example below, an SVG:

```
input {
  width: 198px;
  font-family: monospace;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><line style="stroke: #000" x1="20.090665817260742" y1="-0.08398216962814331" x2="20.090665817260742" y2="20.07965660095215"/></svg>');
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

**Note:** I suspect your teacher will consider this "cheating", especially since you've not written any actual CSS yourself. However, this is one possible real-world solution I might use for this.

https://jsfiddle.net/38a4ffh8/54/

Comment: thanks, but i already solved it; the idea was about the same, sope it's good... anyone know how to close a thread?