# Styling input password in HTML

Tags: html, css, input

I have an input type password that only allow a six-digit number like this:

```
<fieldset>
  <label for="password-input">Enter New Pin</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password-input" inputmode="numeric" minlength="6"
  maxlength="6" size="6" value="">
  <span class="hint">New pin must be 6 digit number only</span>
</fieldset>
```

It will show like this:

[image: Default input appearance]

How can I style it so it can look like the following?

[image: Desired input appearance]

Comment: We can't change the password masking character in input type `password`. We can do it for input type `text` but it has a security risk.

Comment: The fact that all of the answers below fail for at least one person should tell you _not_ to attempt this.

Comment: similare question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49476209/making-a-custom-input-text-type/49476415#49476415

Comment: I would go a different way. Use a single row, 6 cell table with background images and JavaScript/jQuery to process/mask/display. It will give you a lot more visual flexibility than trying to style a password input. It Is probably a lot more work but you can get everything to work and look exactly the way you want.

Comment: @SunKnight0 that would require to implement pasting from clipboard too for people with password managers.

Answer (score 25):

Since you can't use the `::after` pseudo-element on your input box, use it on `fieldset` (or if you can alter the HTML, add an element). Then give it a `content` value using underscores, and position the elements where you want them. Finally, add `letter-spacing` and `width` to your `input` box, and give it a `:focus` of `outline: none` to get rid of the blue box.

```css
fieldset {
  color: #555;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: none;
  position: relative;
}

fieldset > * {
  display: block;
}

fieldset::after {
  content: "___  ___  ___  ___  ___  ___";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  white-space: pre;
}

label {
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

input#password-input {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 2;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  width: 300px;
  text-indent: 9px;
  letter-spacing: 25.6px;
  font-family: Courier;
}

input#password-input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

span.hint {
  margin-top: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
}

span.hint::before {
  content: "* ";
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <label for="password-input">Enter New Pin</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password-input" inputmode="numeric" minlength="6" maxlength="6" size="6" value="">
  <span class="hint">New pin must be 6 digit number only</span>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: @Ferrybig I set the font-family for input. Better?

Comment: @symlink the cursor is out of place for the last input

Comment: @blue That's expected; there's nothing that can be done about that really.

Comment: Width is wrong on Firefox - 5 characters get spread evenly over 6 underscores

Comment: Closer, but still off - by the 5th dot it's shifted to between the 5th and 6th underscores

Comment: @Izkata how about now? If not, can you post a screenshot?

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```css
input {
  padding-left: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 39px;
  border: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, black 70%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: 50px 3px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position-x: 35px;
  width: 280px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <label for="password-input">Enter New Pin</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password-input" inputmode="numeric" minlength="6" maxlength="6" size="6" value="">
  <span class="hint">New pin must be 6 digit number only</span>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: the input font is too small, and when i enter the in put there is a blue border surrounding it, and when i enter the last character the input alignment become messy

Comment: This is actually the only answer that has the letter spacing right on Chromium on Ubuntu, but too bad there is a bug after the sixth character

Comment: @Ferrybig yes fixing that bug will update code shortly :)

Comment: @Ferrybig I hope you don't expect everyone to be able to test fonts for Ubuntu, because it's not as common as a Windows PC or even a OSX Mac . The font in my answer is Consolas and your machine doesn't recognize it. Change the font-family to something your machine recognizes.

Comment: Ubuntu is quite common, according to w3schools, more than 5% of their visitors use it: https://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_os.asp and that considering most people had a time they avoided that website

Comment: 5% wow and what is Win or Mac? Nevermind about changing font-family I added sans serif and monospace.

Comment: @blue here is an improved version of the solution : https://jsfiddle.net/c2zdaypn/

Comment: @blue yes I know, this is the only way to avoid the miss alignment when at the last character ... you can then hide it for example : https://jsfiddle.net/c2zdaypn/1/

Comment: @VikasJadhav I know :) this is the only way to avoid the missalignment, we need to keep space for the cursor after the last character and for this the input need to be bigger and I used negative margin to compensate

Comment: @Ferrybig I don't want to start a discussion on W3schools, but W3schools is not exactly an accurate representation of the average user. W3schools is a site aimed at webdesigners, a group that has an above-average use of non-Windows machines. All Linux systems put together only have about 1.5% representation on a more average stat collector like http://gs.statcounter.com/os-market-share/desktop/worldwide

Comment: @isanae Reproduced.

Answer (score 7):

#Update

- Added a `<input type='number'>` which can adjust the root `font-size: 8px` to `84px`.

#Relevant Points

- The input is stripped of border, outline, and background.
- Wrapped a label around the input as an overlay (technically it is an underlay? `z-index: -1`) which has a pseudo-class `::after` with the `content` value of 6 underscores.
- Both input and overlay must have the following properties:

  ```css
    /* The values can anything as long as it is valid and are the same */
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: 900;
  ```
- The overlay is `display: table` and the input is `display: table-cell`. This (along with `absolute` and `relative` positioning) keeps the input rigidly centered in the overlay.
- `rem` units are used so if you want to scale the `font-size` up or down, just change the `font-size` of the `<html>` tag and everything adjusts accordingly:

  ```css
    /* Change the 16px to whatever you want and everything scale to that value */
    html, 
    body {
      font: 400 16px/1.5 Consolas
    }
  ```

---

##Demo
**Note:** Try keeping a key pressed continuously, and you'll see that there's no shifting.

```js
var node = document.querySelector('#fSz');
node.oninput = setFontSize;

function setFontSize(e) {
  var tgt = e.target;
  var root = document.documentElement;
  root.style.setProperty(`--${tgt.id}`, `${tgt.valueAsNumber}px`);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --fSz: 16px;
}

html,
body {
  font-size: var(--fSz);
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: Consolas, 'sans serif', monospace;
}

fieldset {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  min-height: 5.5rem;
  padding: 0 0 0 0.3125rem;
  margin-top: 2em;
  overflow: visible;
}

fieldset * {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

legend {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.overlay {
  display: table;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.3125rem;
  left: 0.9375rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.overlay::after {
  content: '\ff3f\ff3f\ff3f\ff3f\ff3f\ff3f';
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.78rem;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .overlay::after {
    content: '\2501\2501\2501\2501\2501\2501';
    text-shadow: 0.65rem 0px 0px #222;
    font-size: 1.37rem;
    letter-spacing: 1.2rem;
    line-height: 2;
  }
}

.hint {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2rem;
  left: 0.625rem;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

#password-input {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 0px none transparent;
  outline: 0px none transparent;
  background: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 2;
  transform: translate(0.25rem, -1rem);
  letter-spacing: 1.25rem;
  font-size: 1.35rem;
  font-weight: 900;
}

sup {
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.65rem
}

.fc {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  font: 400 16px/1.5 Consolas;
  width: 50%;
}

#fSz {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 8px;
  width: 52px;
  font: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<label for='fSz' class='fc'>Font-Size: 
  <input id='fSz' type='number' min='8' max='84' value='16' step='0.5'>&nbsp;px
  </label>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Enter New Pin</legend>
  <label for='chk' class='overlay'>
     <input type="password" name="password" id="password-input" inputmode="numeric" minlength="6" maxlength="6" size="19" value="123456" placeholder='123456'>
     </label>
  <label for="password-input" class="hint"><sup>&#128956;</sup>New pin must be 6 digit number only</label>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks Mr. O, I never thought to use the formatting comments on the answer before.

Comment: Your letter spacing is too small on Chromium on the Ubuntu OS: https://i.imgur.com/MT5dYpU.png

Comment: Change `letter-spacing` on `.overlay` and `<input>` and make sure they have the same value.

Comment: Actually after looking at the screenshot, I believe it's because Ubuntu OS doesn't recognizes Consolas font-family. Try a monospaced font comparable to Consolas.

Comment: Looks ugly on Firefox 62, Windows 10: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeEHr.png

Comment: @isanae how about now?

Comment: I get a red border when focus is lost and the caret looks ugly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/loID7.png

Comment: The border shouldn't show anymore and as for the "ugly" cursor, I don't' think it's possible to change cursor when inside the textbox without a plugin.

Comment: Still a red border: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWYn6.png. The caret now behaves weirdly if the input is given focus when some characters are already entered: 1) I can't reposition it by clicking, only with arrow keys; 2) If I put it at the beginning of the input, pressing delete moves the caret forwards. Since you sound pretty annoyed, I won't test your stuff further. Firefox 62, Windows 10.

Answer (score 7):

You can place an element containing "the mask" behind the input and set the background color of input to transparent. But pay attention to the following details:

- Use monospace font family so that the width of `_` and `•` is always the same.
- End your font list with `monospace` so that OS can choose a fixed width font if all of the specified fonts are unavailable.
- User agent could choose a different font family, size and line height for input elements. It can also choose a different size and line height for monospace fonts (e.g. `medium` size could be computed as 13px instead of the usual 16px and `normal` line height is often off by 1px for two different fonts having same size). So make sure you specify these properties explicitly.

Here is the result:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

fieldset label,
fieldset span {
  display: block;
  margin: .5em 0;
}

fieldset .input-wrapper {
  /* positioning */
  position: relative;
  /* font */
  font: 16px/1.5 monospace;
  letter-spacing: .5em;
  /* optional */
  background-color: #EEE;
}

fieldset .input-wrapper::before {
  /* positioning */
  position: absolute;
  /* masking */
  content: "______";
}

fieldset input {
  /* positioning */
  position: relative;
  /* font */
  font: inherit;
  letter-spacing: inherit;
  /* masking */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* reset */
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <label for="password-input">Enter New Pin</label>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password-input" inputmode="numeric" minlength="6" maxlength="6" value="">
  </div>
  <span class="hint">New pin must be 6 digit number only</span>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Unlike the more-highly-upvoted answers, this one is spaced correctly in Firefox.  Kinda makes me wonder if it looks funky in Chrome...

Comment: @Izkata I only checked in Chrome :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: page result]

This conventional solution may help for cross browser :

The HTML form :

```
<p class="text-center">Enter new pins</p>
     <form role="form" method="post">
        <div class="form-group text-center">

                <input class="inputbox"  maxlength="1" type="password" >
                <input class="inputbox"  maxlength="1" type="password" >
                <input class="inputbox"  maxlength="1" type="password" >
                <input class="inputbox"  maxlength="1" type="password" >
                <input class="inputbox"  maxlength="1" type="password" >
                <input class="inputbox"  maxlength="1" type="password" >

                <small class="text-danger">New pin must be 6 digit number only</small>      
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Verify Pin
            </button>
        </div>
        <input id="code_hidden" maxlength="6" name="real_code" type="text" >
    </form>
```

We can see the result on input name = real_code. It must be type = 'hidden' on production. Change this maxlength when more field is required.

Style CSS :

```
<style>
.inputbox {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: thin solid gray;
    width: 20px;
    font-size: 24px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
</style>
```

Script part :

```
<script>
    $(function() {

    $(".inputbox").keyup(function () { 

        $(this).next('.inputbox').focus();

        var value = [];

        $('.inputbox').each(function() {
          value += $(this).val();  
        }); 

         $('#code_hidden').val(value); 
        });
    });

    </script>
```