# How do we escape some special characters inside input with type password with value 12-123456 look like **-******

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, passwords

I have a custom component PasswordInput which has a visibility icon which we can click on to change the input from

```
<input type=“text” value=“12-123455” />
```

To

```
<input type=“password” value=“12-123456” />
```

But we see the value as ••••••••• 
This is including the “-“ char .

So is there any way we could instead be able to show ••-••••••

And escape the “-“ character from hiding

Comment: Not possible with a password input.

Comment: please have a look here ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52885890/styling-input-password-in-html

Answer (score 1):

If the dash has a fixed position in all passwords, you could make it 2 seperate password fields with a hardcoded "-" inbetween